# How to give top offset to a sticky bar as I have a fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, sidebar

I found a codepen example which I was looking for only problem is how do I give a top offset of 70px for the sticky sidebar

```
  var stickySidebar = $('.sticky');

 if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {    
  var stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height(),
  sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
  }

  // on scroll move the sidebar
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {  
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
        stickySidebar.css('top', scrollTop - sidebarTop);

      // stop the sticky sidebar at the footer to avoid overlapping
    var sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight,
      stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
  if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
    var stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
    stickySidebar.css('top', stopPosition);
  }
}
else {
  stickySidebar.css('top', '0');
} 
 }
  });

 $(window).resize(function () {
   if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {  
    stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
   }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/cheryllaird/pen/Ddcxr/

Answer (score 1):

I have added `70px` offset top, when sticky bar reaches top here is the updated snippet.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRMXaG

Comment: The page keeps reloading in a loop.